# Is there a working download link for GlassfishSvc.jar?

Tags: windows-services, glassfish

I want to use the method from this blog, http://www.ryandelaplante.com/2009/08/in-past-i-have-chosen-to-use-commercial.html, but the download links for GlassfishSvc.jar are broken. Every other site that has this method seem to use the same download link. So does any one have this jar and could send it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download it from GoogleCode:

http://acacia-business-ace.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1573/trunk/docs/Installation/service/GlassfishSvc.jar